# Excel VBA Variable in URL

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I would like to include a variable in a Google search URL. The URL, at present is:

IE.Navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=**DNR-12-1G**+$+Price"

How would I replace the emboldened URL text with a defined string variable such as "pn"?
Thanks

Comment: PS - I would also like to know how to replace the above with the contents of a cell.

Answer (score 1):

To use a variable all you need is to substitute the text with it

```
IE.Navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & pn & "+$+Price"
```

That would do the job.  If you wanted to use the content of a cell, either set pn to the cell value like this:

```
pn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
```

Adjust as necessary for your worksheet and cell address... or refer to it directly in the `Navigate` step:

```
IE.Navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value & "+$+Price"
```